# Problems with Apache Service

Tags: apache-http-server, services

I am running Windows 7 and I was trying to uninstall Apache version 2.0.63 and install the Apache 2.0.54 version.  Everytime I tried to install the 2.0.54 version it showed that the service was already installed.  I deleted the Apache2 service through the registry editor.  And now when I have installed the 2.0.54 version I can't either stop or start the service and I can't find Apache2 service in the 'services' list.  when I type in {http://localhost} in the browser it  shows me "It works" but when I try to run a PHP script it says could not connect to local host.  Could you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is usually straightforward to install Apache both on Windows and Linux. You can try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for example – it comes with everything. Just follow the instructions.